# How to retrieve the facebook ID associated to a custom open graph object URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have defined a custom object *`my_object`* and created one instance hosted in *`my_url`* with the metatags:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="my_app_id" />
<meta property="og:type" content="my_namespace:my_object" />
<meta property="og:url" content="my_url" />
<meta property="og:title" content="my_title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="my_description" />
```

I was able to like this object within my app using its *`my_url`* as identifier. Now I want to retrive information about this particular instance as described in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/#retrieve

i.e., I want to perform a:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/1015012577744568
```

But the documentation simply doesn't mention where this `1015012577744568` numeric ID comes from. I only have *`my_url`* as identifier, and the following query doesn't work:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/my_url
```

So the question is: **How do I get this facebook numeric ID for my object instance?**

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+how+to+get+object-instance-id – was that so hard …?

Comment: CBroe, I think I've tried that :) The only relevant result is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184523/determine-object-id-of-a-url-to-use-with-the-facebook-open-graph. This applies for web links, but I tested it and it doesn't work for custom objects.

Comment: Same for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210721/how-can-i-get-the-facebook-object-id-for-a-new-web-page. Both options return the ID of type "link", suggesting that it interpretes my_url as a simple website and not actually the instance of my custom object.